# Exporting CALayer with implicit animation via AVExportSession

Tags: ios, animation, calayer, avmutablecomposition

I'm trying to export an animation for my custom CALayer with a custom property via AVExportSession, please find the setup below:

```
class CustomAnimatable: CALayer
{
    @NSManaged var brightness: CGFloat

    override init(layer: Any) {
        super.init(layer: layer);

        if let l = layer as? CustomAnimatable {
            self.brightness = l.brightness;
        }
    }

    override func action(forKey event: String) -> CAAction?
    {
        if event == "brightness" {
            let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: event);
            animation.fromValue = presentation()?.brightness ?? self.brightness;
            return animation;
        }

        return super.action(forKey: event);
    }

    override class func needsDisplay(forKey key: String) -> Bool
    {
        if key == "brightness" {
            return true;
        }

        return super.needsDisplay(forKey: key);
    }

    override func display()
    {
        print("\(self) \(presentation()?.brightness) \(self.brightness)")
    }
}
```

Here's the export session pre-setup:

```
func render()
{
     ......

    let parentLayer = CALayer();
    let videoLayer = CALayer();
    let animationLayer = CustomAnimatable()

    parentLayer.frame = frame;
    videoLayer.frame = frame;
    animationLayer.frame = frame;

    parentLayer.addSublayer(videoLayer);
    parentLayer.addSublayer(animationLayer);

    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(2.2);
    CATransaction.setDisableActions(true);
    CATransaction.setAnimationTimingFunction(CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear))

    let anim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "brightness");

    anim.fromValue = 1.0;
    anim.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth;
    anim.beginTime = AVCoreAnimationBeginTimeAtZero;
    anim.repeatCount = 1;
    anim.toValue = 0.0;
    anim.isRemovedOnCompletion = false;

    animationLayer.add(anim, forKey: "anim")

    CATransaction.commit()


    let videoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition();

    videoComposition.renderSize = CGSize(width: width, height: height);
    videoComposition.instructions = [mainInstruction];
    videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30);
    videoComposition.animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(postProcessingAsVideoLayer: videoLayer, in: parentLayer);

     ....
}
```

The issue is that the `brightness` value in the resulting video goes from 1 to 0 without animation. If I attempt to animate `CALayer`'s native properties, e.g. `opacity` - the exported animation video is totally fine, the opacity smoothly fades from 1 to 0.

Am I doing it wrong for custom property?

Things I've considered:

- wrapping the explicit animation into `CATransaction` to disable implicit actions
- setting animation begin time to `AVCoreAnimationBeginTimeAtZero` and `isRemovedOnCompletion` to false as per "[Editing Media with AV Foundation](http://docs.huihoo.com/apple/wwdc/2010/session_407__editing_media_with_av_foundation.pdf)" session (Core Animation Gotchas section)

I'm a bit confused by the fact that native CALayer properties animate fine, thus the export session setup seems to be correct.

Besides that, if I add the custom layer to a view and animate the `brightness` property - it also animates fine. So the issue seems to be specific to rendering custom property animation w/ AVExportSession.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why you have added both class `videoLayer` and `animationLayer` in `parentLayer?`.

```
parentLayer.addSublayer(videoLayer);
parentLayer.addSublayer(animationLayer);
```

Use following code Hope will helpful to you!

```
parentLayer.addSublayer(videoLayer);
videoLayer.addSublayer(animationLayer);
```

Comment: I've built the layer composition the same way as in Apples' example (other tutorials suggest the same way of doing that). See here https://github.com/master-nevi/WWDC-2010/blob/e2b5e586bfea16e247a59cdc6b1d00e8db40ee22/AVEditDemo/Classes/SimpleEditor.m#L425

Anyway changing the parent of the animated layer doesn't change the outcome - native CALayer `opacity` is rendered fine, the custom property doesn't get animated.